# One-line difference in c++ template

Tags: c++

I've been given some classes, and only one use **.open** method, while the others use **.load**

Is there any *smarter* way to achieve something like the (simplified) code below? Or should I edit the aforementioned classes' definitions?

```
template <class element> bool load (element & el, std::string file) {
    bool status;
    if (std::is_same <element, some_special_class>::value) {
        status = el.open (file);
    } else {
        status = el.load (file);
    }
    // lot of code, based on status
    return status;    
}
```

This seems a little better

```
void lotOfCode (bool status) {
    if (status) {
        // some code
    } else {
        // more code
    }
}
template <class el> bool load (el & e, std::string f) {
    bool status = e.load (f);
    lotOfCode (status);
    return status;
}
bool load (some_special_class & e, std::string f) {
    bool status = e.open (f);
    lotOfCode (status);
    return status;
}
```

than this

```
template <class element> bool load (element & el, std::string file) {
    if (el.load (file)) {
        // some code
        return true; // loaded
    }
    // more code
    return false;
}

bool load (some_special_class & el, std::string file) {
    if (el.open (file)) {
        // some code
        return true; // loaded
    }
    // more code
    return false;
}
```

but is it good enough?

Comment: Unless both classes have `open` **and** `load`, the first version won't compile. Regardless. Your instincts are very good. Overloading is superior to huge template functions with a bunch of  `std::is_same` conditionals. Whomever gave you those classes doesn't understand c++ as well as they think.

Comment: Your code wins.

Comment: You can wait for `if constexpr` in C++17? :D

Comment: The version using `std::is_same` is not quite equivalent to all the others. It only does the special case when `element` is exactly `some_special_class`, whereas the versions using overloading also apply the special case to types implicitly convertible to `some_special_class` - e.g. classes derived from it.

Comment: Can you change the original classes ? Doing what you suggest  seems to me like hiding a problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller _Unless both classes have open and load, the first version won't compile_ - that was exactly my problem.

And well, they do: `load` is used to load the entire file in memory (and can used even if deleted if process is not yet terminated), while `open` is used to just open the file (can be used while the file is still on disk)
But, in this particular code, it's not important _how_ the files are loaded (to their respective classes)

Thanks @IgorTandetnik, I'll use that in future code,
but in this one, there's no class derived from/implicitly convertible to `some_special_class`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the actual code isn't as simple as posted, it *may* be reasonable to customize the function template with an operation which is actually applied. For example:

```
template <typename T>
bool load_aux(T& t, std::string const& s) { return t.load(s); }
bool load_aux(some_special_case& t, std::string const& s) { return t.open(s); }

template <typename T>
bool load(T& t, std::string const& s) {
    if (load_aux(t, s)) {
        // some code
        return true;
    }
    // some more code
    return false;
}
```

Comment: So this (way better than my second attempt) is the only way?

Comment: @EdwinIsBack: there are, obviously, multiple solutions. Which is most appropriate depends on the actual use. In the case you described I think my proposal to provide a common notation for the different operations is fairly straight forward. If the function is called from different location it my be reasonable to rather pass in lambda function to customize the common function.

Comment: As long as it works. But inserting a trivial interface to enforce naming consistency seems (to me) less ad-hoc and more readable and maintainable that what you proposed. Note how the interface preserves the singularity of each class, can be isolated in its own namespace, can be easily reused by other functions, etc.

Comment: @n.caillou: it actually depends on the situation. When the customization can be keyed of the type using the approach shown in the answer is likely a reasonable one. It isn't the only one, though. In particular, if the customization may depend on the actual use passing in the used function can be a reasonable approach, too.